# How can I update knowledge base via QnA Maker API v4.0?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to call the QnA Maker API v4.0 with the following request:

```
PATCH https://my-test-site.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/1d2fb9b0-cc8b-41a4-abbe-3bcb2e497220
Authorization: EndpointKey xxxx
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "add": {
        "qnaList": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "answer": "Well, hi to you too!",
                "questions": [ "Hi there" ]
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

I get the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
{
    "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'."
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Does the v4.0 API not support this? The documentation is a bit weird an seems to be missing bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the API documentation available here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da7600

It looks like you should call the following:

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/{kbId}
```

And not your own Azure QnAMaker website. So replace `my-test-site.azurewebsites.net` with `westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com` and try again.

EDIT: I made a test with my own KB and can confirm that **you have to use Microsoft cognitive endpoint**, not your Azure's one.
You will have a `202 Accepted` reply with an OperationId provided.

You can then check the operation status with "Get Operation Details" method. 
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/operations_getoperationdetails

Comment: Are you sure? That was the way the API was called in the preview. Now that QnA Maker is GA, I was under the impression that you should use the API created in your own Web App. Though the documentation is very unclear about this, when you create a new QnA service and knowledgebase, it gives you the request to test the API and it is the same URL we are using. We will be testing this anyway and I’ll get back to you with the results.

Comment: Before the GA everything was under microsoft endpoint yes. Now you have to use your own endpoint during the query to search answers in your KB, but they have split the API between querys and administration. You can see on the API documentation I'm pointing that there is no more "generateAnswer" method there, compared to v2 or v3 (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa). It's confusing and yes, I definitely would like to have your feedback on your test

Comment: Added an edit: just tested it, it's working well with westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com endpoint (got 202 accepted, then my KB was updated)

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely right. We tested the https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com URL before but with the end point key authentication and got a 401 and incorrectly thought that it meant we were doing something wrong. But in reality we just had to change the endpointkey authentication to subscription key authentication. After I added the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header with the correct key that I got from the Azure Portal it started to work.

Comment: and what about train ? there was a train api earlier... now in v4.0 only update is there and no separate train api. Does update api train too? nothing mentioned in the documentation....

Comment: @UdayaBhaskarReddy : already replied here about train operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925428/3136339