# QnA Maker missing train endpoint

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

API V4 documentation is missing Train endpoint or is the feature missing in the GA-version?

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff

Comment: I was just wondering this too. I think it's combined with publish, but the documentation is not clear at all. V4 also seems to be missing generateanswer.

Comment: the generateanswer has moved to the webapp endpoint.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401507/training-qna-maker-with-api-v4-0

Comment: I added a reply on the original question which is duplicated here as Microsoft team replied on Github

Answer (score 1):

Official reply has been made on Github issue by Prashant Choudhari from Microsoft:

> We do not have the train API in V4. We are re-thinking this feature
>   and will re-enable an advanced version in a future release.

See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/106